# Read text from .txt file started from other line php laravel

Tags: laravel, file, txt

how can i read file from input file txt from certain line, example from line prefix AT on php [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJyQH.png)

can u help to continue my script
`

```
  $data = $request->file('file');
        $filetmp = $data->getRealPath();
        $readfile = file_get_contents($filetmp);
        $files = fopen($filetmp,"r");
        $filedata = fread($files,filesize($filetmp));
        fclose($files);
        dd($filedata);
```

Comment: So you want to skip a few lines... how about: 1) read the full file, 2) make a proper array or `collection` from that file 3) dump (`reject`) from the array or collection the lines that you don't want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$file=$request->file('file');
$content=File::get($file->getRealPath());
$lines = explode("\n", $content);
$lines=array_slice($lines,
 array_keys(
  array_filter($lines, 
   function($item){
   return strpos($item,'AT') ;
   }))[0]

  );
```

Comment: hallo sir i got error message like this sir array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

Comment: I forgot the first parameter of array_filter. I  updated the answer

Comment: thnk you so much sirr!!thnnks sir

Comment: sory sir, can u help me for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74948728/insert-value-txt-file-into-mysql-laravel-6