# insert value txt file into mysql laravel 6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, input, txt

how can I insert value from my input file.txt like this to MySQL, these [example image] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/v16fi.png).
and I just need atm_id, name_atm, ip, and status agent_connection
my code is like

```
`   $data = $request->file('file');
        $filetmp = $data->getRealPath();
        $filedata = file_get_contents($filetmp);
        $lines = explode("\n", $filedata);
        $lines=array_slice($lines,
        array_keys(
         array_filter($lines, 
          function($item){
          return strpos($item,'PAR') ;
          }))[0]
         );
        $arrays = array_map(function($array) {
            $columns = ['atm_id', 'name_atm', 'ip', 'agent_connection',];
            return array_combine($columns, array_map('trim', $array));
        }, array_chunk($lines, 5));
        dd($arrays);`
```

I expect I can insert just

`atm_id = AT8502 atm_name = example ip = 10.51.7.50 agent_connection = complete`

as much as data on txt file.

Comment: Hi have you checked this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250330/how-to-import-a-text-file-to-mysql-direct-or-through-php

Comment: im sory sir,i think diffrent,but thanks for information

Comment: How to get atm_id , name_atm , ... from array?I mean which part of string includes these data?

Comment: Can you upload your txt file?

Comment: this sir (https://i.stack.imgur.com/v16fi.png) atention on array indexs 0 first sentences atmid= AT825802, name_atm = ATM KCP PEKANBARU ip=10.51.7.50 and agent connection = complate

Comment: i just want insert that item from long string in every arry indexs